# Content-Disposition utf8 encoding (golang)

Tags: file, http, go, utf-8, attachment

It is implementing a file download API

The problem is that the Korean file name is broken

text: "AWS자산.svg"

my code ↓

```
import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "net/url"
)

 func FileDownload(c *gin.Context) {
    result, infos := fileDownload(c)
    if result.Code == 200 {
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Content-Type", infos.FileType)
        /* infos.FileOgName = AWS자산.svg */
        c.FileAttachment(infos.FilePath, infos.FileOgName) // 1 image
        c.FileAttachment(infos.FilePath, url.QueryEscape(infos.FileOgName)) // 2 image
    } else {
        c.JSON(result.Code, result)
    }
}
```

```
// 3 image
func (c \*Context) FileAttachment(filepath, filename string) { 
    c.Writer.Header().Set("content-disposition", fmt.Sprintf(attachment; filename\*="UTF-8''%s", filename))
    http.ServeFile(c.Writer, c.Request, filepath)
}
```

I conducted three tests

1. I sent you a pure file name.
   [test 1 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZI7zy.png)
2. url encoding
   [test 2 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUNiA.png)
3. Apply by referring to the Internet (filename*="UTF-8''%s")
   [test 3 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsYlL.png)

The problem has not been solved.

I need help from good developers

----------2022-12-09 update-----------

[go gin 1.8.1]
The module update has been completed, but the problem remains.

```
// FileAttachment writes the specified file into the body stream in an efficient way
// On the client side, the file will typically be downloaded with the given filename
func (c *Context) FileAttachment(filepath, filename string) {
    if isASCII(filename) {
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", `attachment; filename="`+filename+`"`)
    } else {
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", `attachment; filename*=UTF-8''`+url.QueryEscape(filename))
    }
    http.ServeFile(c.Writer, c.Request, filepath)
}
```

[test 4 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MK8Ll.png)

Comment: `c.FileAttachment("go.mod", "AWS자산.svg")` by itself works fine on my end. https://i.stack.imgur.com/myZDP.png . Using `github.com/gin-gonic/gin v1.8.1`

Comment: `filename\*="UTF-8''%s", filename` - that's not how [RFC 2231](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2231) works. The filename must be url-encoded.

Comment: @abdusco Thank you. [go gin] update complete 

c.Writer.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", `attachment; filename*=UTF-8''`+url.QueryEscape(filename))
This line has been added.

But the problem remains.